# Modify Crash_manager on Odoo_13

Tags: javascript, odoo-13, qweb

Hello guys I'm trying to modify the error window that odoo shows when an error occurs to only shows the button see details and copy to clipboard to specific user groups, I tried to change the crash_manager.xml on web module, but the changes made only can be seen when I'm in developer mode in odoo, and I don't have good knowledge in JavaScript to change the crash_manager.js but if you can give me an insight of how achieve this, you will help me a lot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [patch](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class) the [crash_manager](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class) class, you will need to understand how Odoo [manage assets](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#assets-management).

You have to include the script in the `web.assets_backend` which contains the code specific to the web client.

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="My assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/<Module name>/static/src/js/crash_manager.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

In the following code, we will define a new widget attribute `visibility`that we can use later in the template to control the visibility of the buttons:

```js
odoo.define('<Module name>.CrashManager', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var ErrorDialog = require('web.CrashManager').ErrorDialog;
    var session = require('web.session');
    ErrorDialog.include({
        init: function (parent, options, error) {
            var self = this;
            this._super.apply(this, [parent, options, error]);
            // this.visibility = session.is_system?'visible': "hidden";
            session.user_has_group('base.group_system').then(function(has_group){
                self.visibility = has_group?'visible': "hidden";
            });
        },
    });
});
```

Hiding `Details` and `Copy` buttons will make the message obsolete, so you need to change it.

In the following example, we alter the `CrashManager.error` template to define a `style` attribute for the `Copy the full error to clipboard` and `See details` buttons:

```
<t t-extend="CrashManager.error">
    <t t-jquery="div.float-right" t-operation="attributes">
        <attribute name="t-att-style">'visibility: ' + widget.visibility</attribute>
    </t>
    <t t-jquery="button" t-operation="attributes">
        <attribute name="t-att-style">'visibility: ' + widget.visibility</attribute>
    </t>
</t>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made all the steps you recomend only changing the group from 'base.group_system' to 'base.group_no_one', but when I take out the test user from the (extra rights/technical features) it keeps showing both buttons.

I already created the .xml file that alters the CrashManager.error template and put it in the manifest of the custom module as a qweb.

Comment: Make sure the script is loaded, you can check [what-to-do-if-a-file-is-not-loaded-updated](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/developer/reference/javascript/javascript_reference.html#what-to-do-if-a-file-is-not-loaded-updated)

Comment: Yeah de script is loaded, I putted a console.log to be sure. Btw I made a change not in the ErrorDialog but in the CrashManager (specifically in the show_error function) where I used the session.user_has_group() to see if the user belongs to the designed group and then change the visibility of buttons and the text where it says copy the error with the button, I don't Know if is the best way but it worked, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I tested the code in a new database with the demo user and the two buttons are well hidden.

Comment: the .js file is working fine I guess the problem is in qweb (.xml) file by my part, just to be sure, I created a (static/src/xml/crash_manager_hide.xml) file with the code you shared, then in the __manifest__.py I added  ('qweb': ['static/src/xml/crash_manager_hide.xml',],) is that okay or I did something wrong?

Comment: Put the code inside the ``templates`` tag

Comment: @omaramaya Does this answer help you?

Comment: Yes and no, it gives the base yo make the solution, but I had yo change diferently the js script, but I think is a good way yo do it if Someone has to do the same